# Enterprise app for different vendors of one single organization

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise

I created an Enterprise app for an organization. This organization has different vendors. My application will be used by the agents of these different vendors. Can I use one single Enterprise application for all these vendors?

Comment: First, are the agents employees of the organisation?  If not then you can't use an enterprise app. If they are, then the question is really up to you. Can you make one app that suits all of the different vendors?

Comment: @Paulw11, Thanks for your prompt response. Could you please suggest alternatives for this?

Comment: B2B apps are the recommended approach for this situation.  This video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/304/ Explains the various options and when you would use each one.

Comment: @Paulw11, thank you so much for the valuable information.